# Why does this homogeneous ODE not have a standard form solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, finance

I'm studying finance, looking through Dixit & Pindyck's *Investment under uncertainty*. They have this homogeneous 2nd order ODE, where F(V) is a function of V:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 V^2 F''(V) + (\rho-\delta)VF'(V) - \rho F = 0 \tag{1}$$

F(V) must satisfy three boundary conditions:

$$F(0) = 0 \tag{2}$$

$$F(V^*) = V^*-I \tag{3}$$

$$F'(V^*) = 1 \tag{4}$$

From high school, I remember that a 2nd order ODE can be

$$c_1e^{r_1x} + c_2e^{r_2x} \tag{5}$$

$$c_1e^{rx} + xc_2e^{rx} \tag{6}$$

$$e^{\alpha x}(c_1sin(\beta x) + c_2cos(\beta x)) \tag{7}$$

Where (5) is for real, distinct roots, (6) is for real, repeated roots and (7) is for complex roots $\alpha \pm \beta i$.

(1) is a homongeneous, 2nd order ODE, so I would assume the solution would be in the form (5), (6) or (7). However, without further ado, the authors of my finance textbook write

> To satisfy the boundary condition (2), the solution must take the form
>
> $$F(V) = AV^{\beta _1}$$

This solution doesn't look like neither (5), (6) nor (7). Like, where's the $e$? Why is the solution of this homogeneous, 2nd order ODE *not* in the expected form?

Comment: 5 6 7 are for second order DE with constant coefficients and this is not the case for the Euler Cauchy equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions you remember are for a **constant coefficient** second order linear homogeneous equation. In your equations the coefficients are not constant, and your equation is in fact a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), where the solutions are linear combinations of powers of $V$ (or a bit worse in some cases, depending on the coefficients).